# Execute a script with root permission

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu: let a user run a script with root permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/75620/ubuntu-let-a-user-run-a-script-with-root-permissions)

Hi all,

I need a script that will chown/chmod some files.
This script need to be executable by any user.

The problem is that those files are owned by different users, so it needs to be executed as root.

I tried the SUID so that any users with X permission can execute the script as root, but seems that it doesn't work with a bash script because of security issue.

How can I do that ? thanks.

Comment: You want sudo for this, see the possible duplicate link above.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are listed in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
sudo scriptname
```

Comment: The user is member of a group 'adm', and in visudo I have :
%adm    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

Comment: In fact, I don't want the user to write in a password to sudo, is that possible to do it another way ? I just want him to execute the script and that's it.